# .gitignoreに記載したファイルがGithubにpushされてしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

現在作成しているアプリで下記ディレクトリをGitHubには上げたくないので、
「.gitignore」ファイルに以下のように記述しました。

【.gitignore】※sample_app/.gitignore

```
/app/views/categories/
/app/views/chat/
/app/views/question_mailer/
```

その後、

```
git add -A
git commit -m "add_.gitignore"
git push -u origin master
```

を行いました。
が、GitHubを確認すると、「.gitignore」ファイルに記載したディレクトリがGitHubにアップされてしまっています。
これは「.gitignore」ファイルの書き方が間違っているのでしょうか？
間違っている場合は正しい書き方を教えて頂きたいです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `.gitignore` はGithubへ上げない指定というより、今後リポジトリに追加してほしくないファイルを指定するものです。ですから `.gitignore` を書く前にコミットされていたファイルについては適用されませんが、今回はそれに該当していないでしょうか？

Comment: すみません。コメント頂きありがとうございます。上記ディレクトリは.gitignore を書く前にコミットしておりました。

Comment: ところで除外されたいファイルはアプリケーションコードの一部のようですが、これコミットしなくていいんですか？「Gitで管理はしたいけどGithubには載せたくない」というのは.gitignoreでは実現できません。

Comment: やりたいことはGitHubにPUSHする際に上記のディレクトリは上げたくないのですが、そのようなやり方はありますでしょうか？
(.gitignoreでできると勘違いしておりました。)

Comment: この質問は.gitignoreにフォーカスしてしまっているので、「一部ファイルはGithubで公開したくない、けどGitで管理したい」というのは別途質問するといいかもしれません。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/34727

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` は名前の通り、Gitから特定のディレクトリ・ファイルを除外するための指定ですから、

- そのファイルはGithubだけでなくローカルでもGitで管理されなくなります
- リポジトリへの新規追加を抑制するものなので、既にコミットされたファイルには適用されません

`.gitignore` を書く前にコミットしてしまったファイルを取り除きたい場合、当該ファイルを `git rm --cached` することになりますが、当然それまでの履歴には残ったままになります。これも含めて削除するには、ファイルを追加した時点まで遡ってコミットをやり直したり、量が多ければ `git filter-branch` を使うことになります。

> やりたいことはGitHubにPUSHする際に上記のディレクトリは上げたくないのですが、そのようなやり方はありますでしょうか？ .gitignoreで行うか、他のやり方もあるのでしょうか？

Gitの仕組みとして、pushする時にはコミット単位でコピーされますから、コミットのうち一部のファイルだけpushすることはできません。またGithubには特定のファイルを非公開にする機能はありません。

ですから「諦めて公開してしまう」か「Gitの管理外に置いてしまう」のどちらかが多く、時々「非公開用と公開用でリポジトリを分ける」といったケースがあるぐらいかと思います。

Comment: とても分かりやすく説明して頂きありがとうございます！.gitignoreの仕組み勉強になりました。今回は「非公開用と公開用でリポジトリを分ける」やり方にします。アドバイス頂きありがとうございました。